# OWL2: complex class expressions + comparison of two dates

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology

Is there a way in [OWL2](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/) to define a class that involves a comparison of two literal values?
Let's say I have a class `Person` that has two data properties:

- dateA: `Person` -> `xsd:date`
- dateB: `Person` -> `xsd:date`

I want to define two subclasses of the class `Person`:

- PersonWithEarlierDateA = those persons that have `dateA < dateB`
- PersonWithEarlierDateB = those persons that have `dateB < dateA`

The following definition does not seem to work in Protege 5.5.0.: `PersonWithEarlierDateA Equivalent To "dateA some xsd:date[ < dateB ]"` + `PersonWithEarlierDateB Equivalent To "dateB some xsd:date[ < dateA ]"` (Protege crashes when I am trying to infer classes of individuals).

Is it even possible in OWL2?

Comment: not possible in OWL as you don't have a concept of variables. `PersonWithEarlierDateA Equivalent To "dateA some xsd:date[ < dateB ]` - what is that? You can't put a property into the facet restriction. I mean, also what would be the semantics of this? There can be multiple of such values, how would such an OWL expression handle those? "any", "all" ?

Comment: Anyways, there is a rule language on top of OWL called SWRL - you can try to find a way with it.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention I want to restrict cardinality of `dateA` and `dateB` to 1. But I get your point. It's a pitty that you have to use SWRL to do something that easy.

Comment: Aside from the actual OWL2 syntax and semantics, why would I need a concept of variables here? I just want to compare two data properties of the same individual. I can compare a data property to a constant like so `Child Equivalent To "age some xsd:int[ < 18 ]` ([link to the documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Positive_Data_Property_Assertions)), why would it be non-trivial to extend it to comparison of two data properties? The problem is quite easy computationally, right? It's just that OWL2 does not support those constructs.

Comment: why do you think it's "easy"? it's even unclear what it would mean with your example. Would it mean that all values of dateA have to be smaller than dateB, or just there should be one such thing. Also it would take the cartesian product to compare any of A with any of B. Anyways, impossible with OWL, you can try SWRL

Comment: I mean exactly what you wrote. Ideally, I'd like to take the cartesian product and let the user decide which semantics they want, similar to how [complex class expressions](http://protegeproject.github.io/protege/class-expression-syntax/) work.
If that is not possible in OWL2 then is there any other declarative language (OWL/XML/RDF/etc.-based, others are welcome too, except for query languages like SPARQL and SQL) that supports such constructs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [SHACL](https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl/) to define a `NodeShape` that matches `Person` where dateA < dateB. Using [SHACL's Advanced Features](https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl-af/) you could make that `NodeShape` actually build a triple stating that a person with dateA < dateB is actually of type `PersonWithEarlierDateA`.

This is similar to using SWIRL perhaps but SHACL's more recent *and* much more widely used (I'm guessing but I think this is true).